# Comment formuler différemment (en d’autres termes) «Pourrions-nous, pour une rare fois, passer un moment de qualité en famille »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, reformulation

Ma question s’applique moins à l’ensemble qu’à un fragment de la phrase citée en titre, en l’occurence « passer du temps en famille », par là je souhaiterais qu’on me présente une variante équivalente, si jamais il en est une, de ce morceau de phrase, préférablement en d’autres termes, sinon en se passant du verbe « passer ». J’ai pensé recourir au verbe « vivre », comme dans « vivre du temps agréable en famille, ensemble… » mais il me fait hésiter sur sa disposition à préserver le sens de la phrase en question et je me demande aussi, au demeurant, s’il existerait des verbes autres que ceux dont je fais mention qui pourraient être pertinents.

Comment: Il parait que temps de qualité se dit en français: https://www.festival-ecole-de-la-vie.fr/astuces-vivre-temps-de-qualite-enfant/ On trouve aussi: vivre un moment de qualité [en famille] par exemple. *Vivre un temps* veut dire autre chose, à mon avis. J'ai vécu un temps chez ma tante.

Comment: @Lambie Je vous remercie, Lambie, pour cet éclaircissement.

Comment: Il existe beaucoup de variantes équivalentes, et correctes. *passet* et *vivre* conviennent tous les deux.

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir se passer de *passer* ? Quel est le contexte ? Qu'est qui est espéré pour ce moment ? Le style doit-il forcément être très soutenu .

Comment: @jlliagre Dans le seul but d’élargir l’horizon de mes connaissances en matière de formulation. Quant à ta première question, c’est une phrase qui est formulée sur le moment à deux membres de ma famille « proche.. » parce que j’ai le sentiment qu’ils s’éloignent de moi, j’ai l’impression que notre bulle familiale manque de cohésion. Pour ce qui concerne la seconde, j’attends une reformulation de registre soutenu.

Comment: J'ai découvert l'expression *pour une rare fois* avec cette question. Je ne l'avais jamais entendue en France (ou trop peu pour qu'elle m'ait marqué). Elle est peut-être due à *for a rare time*.

Comment: Il s’agirait donc d’un anglicisme?! Je m’efforce de les [les anglicismes] tenir loin de moi car ils polluent la langue française. Merci pour cette précision.

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit d'un anglicisme et si c'en est un, il n'est répertorié nulle part où j'ai cherché. Ce n'est qu'une hypothèse due au fait que toutes les occurrences que les moteurs de recherche retournent proviennent de pages liées au Québec. Cela-dit, ce n'est pas une raison pour éviter de le dire. L'expression sera parfaitement comprise dans toute la francophonie, il n'y a pas de contresens à craindre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un terme moins général que « passer » pourrait être utilisé ;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retrouver))  **se retrouver**  B. − Empl. pronom. réciproque   > 1. Se trouver à nouveau en présence l'un de l'autre, les uns des autres, après une séparation.
> ♦ Il ne savait point encore que l'univers est petit et que l'on se retrouve partout (Radiguet,Bal,1923, p. 25).
> ♦ Que de fois, par exemple, n'ai-je pas souri (...) en voyant, dans un récit qui prétendait me représenter la vie de Paris ou de Londres, cinq ou six personnages, toujours les mêmes, se retrouver par hasard dans les lieux les plus divers (Romains,Hommes bonne vol.,1932, p. xii).

- Pourrions-nous, pour une rare fois, nous retrouver en famille en un moment que l'on voudrait spécial ?

Comment: *en un moment* me semble bizarre aussi. pour passer un moment spécial

Comment: @Lambie « En un moment » signifie presque toujours « Rapidement, en un petit espace de temps » (TLFi), mais ce n'est pas la signification qui est donnée à cette construction dans ma phrase ; c'est peut-être cela qui la rend bizarre. La signification de « en » est « pendant ».

Comment: C'est ça, d'où le trompe-l'oeil (_garden path_). Mais le _moment spécial_ est infiniment courant dans mon sociolecte.

Answer (score 1):

Passer du [*temps de qualité*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=QUALITY%20TIME&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) consiste en fait à *partager des moments privilégiés* avec des gens importants pour nous. On peut simplement parler de *passer des moments agréables* ou *de bons moments* ensemble. On peut d'autre part exprimer le désir d'accorder l'importance ou l'attention nécessaire *à des moments passés ensemble*. On peut aussi parler de *profiter du temps passé en famille* ou de *valoriser* de tels moments. Si on veut parler d'entraide on peut exprimer le désir de voir les gens *se serrer les coudes* davantage ; on peut parler de *rapprochement*. Selon qu'on veuille exprimer la nature du moment, partager sa conception d'une rencontre en famille ou ses attentes etc.